# Is there a way that limit $\lim_{x \to 0}0^{0}$ to have alternative results besides 1?

Tags: limits

That is, is there a way so that

$= \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)^{g(x)}$

where $= \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ and $ \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=0 $ is anything but 1

So is there a way that the limit of $0^{0}$ is not 1 but say, 0?

Could it be .5?

Could it be any other numbers?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Are you asking for the reason why the limit is undefined, and so the convention is that the limit is $1$?

Comment: You should also ask yourself "What should remain the same if I redefine this limit."

Comment: @Chickenmancer: There is no convention for the limit. You’re probably thinking of the simple expression $0^0$.

Comment: @NamburuKarthik: can you substantiate ?

Answer (score 7):

By continuity of the logarithm,

$$\log\left(\lim_{x\to0}f(x)^{g(x)}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}g(x)\log(f(x)).$$

The last expression is an indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$, which is well-known to be able to take an arbitrary value.

---

E.g.

$$(e^{-1/x^2})^{x^2}\to e^{-1},$$
$$(e^{-1/x^4})^{x^2}\to 0,$$
$$(e^{-1/x^4})^{-x^2}\to \infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on Yves Daoust's answer, here is a way to get any real number $C$ you would like. We separate into three cases.

1. If $C>0$, then set $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ and $g(x) = -\log(C) x^2$. You can check that $f$ and $g$ approach $0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, and we get:
   $$
   f(x)^{g(x)}
   =
   e^{(-1/x^2)(-\log(C)x^2)}
   =
   e^{\log(C)} = C
   $$
2. If $C<0$, we just need to adjust a little bit. Take $f(x) = -e^{-1/x^2}$ and $g(x) = -\log(-C)x^2$. This works out just as above, and $\log(-C)$ makes sense since $-C>0$.
3. Finally, if $C=0$, just take $f(x) = e^{-1/x^4}$ and $g(x) = x^2$. The limit of these functions as $x \rightarrow 0$ is still $0$, and we get:
   $$
   f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{-1/x^2}
   $$
   which approaches $0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.